# NSOpenGLView:openGLContext returns nil in DisplayLink callback

Tags: macos, opengl

I have a disappearing context problem. I have a simple subclass of NSOpenGLView. I define the pixel format in initWithFrame and verify that I have a valid context afterward. I do some additional gl setup in awakeFromNib and verify that I still have a valid context. I use a DisplayLink for the main rendering. In the display link callback, [self openGLContext] returns nil. In the debugger, I can see that the _openGLContext instance variable is still valid - but the accessor returns nil. What am I missing?

------ edit: include code -------------

MyGLView.h

```
@interface MyGLView : NSOpenGLView

- (void)displayLinkDraw;

@end
```

MyGLView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    NSOpenGLPixelFormat        *windowedPixelFormat;
    NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute    attribs[] = {
        NSOpenGLPFAWindow,
        NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 32,
        NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
        NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
        NSOpenGLPFASingleRenderer,
        0 };

    windowedPixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attribs];
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect pixelFormat:windowedPixelFormat];

    // set synch to VBL to eliminate tearing
    GLint    vblSynch = 1;
    [[self openGLContext] setValues:&vblSynch forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];

    NSOpenGLContext* context = self.openGLContext;
    // *** self.openGLContext returns valid context here. ***
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSOpenGLContext* context = self.openGLContext;
    // *** self.openGLContext returns valid context here. ***

    [self.openGLContext makeCurrentContext];

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBufferID);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBufferID);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorBufferID);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBufferID);

    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBufferID);
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}

- (void)displayLinkDraw
{
    NSOpenGLContext* context = self.openGLContext;
    // *** self.openGLContext returns nil here??? ***
    [context makeCurrentContext];

    CGLLockContext([context CGLContextObj]);

    glClearColor(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // ...

    [context flushBuffer];

    CGLUnlockContext([context CGLContextObj]);
}
```

MyViewController.m

```
static CVReturn displayLinkCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink, const CVTimeStamp *inNow, const CVTimeStamp *inOutputTime, CVOptionFlags flagsIn, CVOptionFlags *flagsOut, void *displayLinkContext)
{
    MyViewController* self = (__bridge MyViewController *)displayLinkContext;
    MyGLView* glView = self->_myGLView;

    [glView displayLinkDraw];

    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Please read the "how to ask" section and post your code.

Comment: It found a few links that make it sound like an NSOpenGLView context is thread specific. Since the DisplayLink is definitely on a different thread, is a shared context the way around this? Or should I do my initialization on the first DisplayLink callback?

Answer (score 0):

The [GLEssentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html) example application from Apple has a functioning `CGDisplayLink` loop within an `NSOpenGLView` subclass.  Also there is a [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1385/_index.html) from Apple on display link setup.

I have successfully used this approach in my own basic OpenGL animations.
Your `CGDisplayLink` setup code should look something like this (mine is run from my `NSOpenGLView` subclass, yours appears to be set up from your view controller).
If you are not calling `CVDisplayLinkSetCurrentCGDisplayFromOpenGLContext()` with the context and pixel format you set up then it's possible a display link is selected that can't access that context.

```
// Create a display link capable of being used with all active displays
CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&displayLink);

// Set the renderer output callback function
CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink, &displayLinkCallback, (__bridge void *)(self));

// Set the display link for the current renderer
CGLContextObj cglContext = [[self openGLContext] CGLContextObj];
CGLPixelFormatObj cglPixelFormat = [[self pixelFormat] CGLPixelFormatObj];
CVDisplayLinkSetCurrentCGDisplayFromOpenGLContext(displayLink, cglContext, cglPixelFormat);

// Activate the display link
CVDisplayLinkStart(displayLink);
```